# htaccess rewrite rule knowledge

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to rewrite the url of mysite with help of htaccess. My website url which I need to rewrite is given below.
http://getallfreedownloads.com/category.php?slug=business_directory_listing

Result needed
http://getallfreedownloads.com/business_directory_listing or http://getallfreedownloads.com/business_directory_listing/

I have used the below code for rewrite rule in my htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /category.php?slug=$1 [L]
```

Please guide me what I can do to make it work fine.

Note: After adding rewrite rule I have removed the **" category.php?slug= "** from the a Tag

I will be thank full to you all.

Answer (score 0):

try this once.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteRule ^/category.php?slug(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]
```

Comment: after adding this in htaccess file its giving 404 error page you can check it on http://getallfreedownloads.com/

Comment: RewriteRule ^category.php?slug(.*)$ /$1 [L,NC,R]

by removing / try once more

Comment: have you added this code into your root directory .htaccess file right?

Comment: Yes I did and still its showing the 404 error page